# How Databases save VARCHAR in file

Tags: database

I thought DBMS deal with data type s as fixed size. As fixed-sized data is easy to search and fetch. But there is VARCHAR. Then, how DBMS reads sheer row from file; Get not as divided. (They never reads just one record at a time, since it is not efficient.)

So my questions are, How DBMS write varchar on file and how they read the record, having varchar field.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125499/what-is-the-overhead-for-varcharn

Comment: There are as many implementations of data types as there are databases.